# Upload having errors on Appharbor. Good on Local

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, git

```
 if (Upload.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var FileName = Upload.FileName;
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images"), FileName);


            Upload.SaveAs(path);
            cement.ImageLocation = ("/Content/Images/" + FileName);
        }
```

This code is working perfectly in Local IIS hosting. But having problem on AppHarbor. The error that I got from the logging is this.

```
**Message**

An unhandled exception has occurred.

**Exceptions**

[DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Users\apphb9840cac8716388\app\_PublishedWebsites\RMQGrainsBeta\Content\Images\Capture.PNG'.]
```

I tried to read some of the articles about this and Got some Information that that the Folder might be protected or something, so I removed the ReadOnly on the Images folder and try to git bash, the problem is. GitBash doesn't recognize the difference and won't push the changes of the folder.

Comment: I can't see that code as compiling because you declared `var path` twice.

Comment: oh sorry, it is suppose to be a comment block while I am trying to figure the problem Editing now.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got an answer from AppHarbor. So the thing is, it is not the code that is having the problem. It is the AppHarbor services that is blocking us to upload or directly access the file system. Here is what the Tech from the AppHarbor says.

```
About storing images: AppHarbor does not allow write access to the  
application directory by default. This is because the local filesystem is   
ephemeral and may be wiped on each deployment and/or during system 
maintenance.     For this reason it needs to be manually enabled on the 
settings page, and it     should only be used for temporary storage purposes such as caching.



I'd recommend using a cloud file storage solution such as Amazon S3. You can 
upload files to S3 from your application or the client can upload files 
directly to Amazon S3 by using presigned URLs. This will allow you to build
a scalable, distributed file storage feature that is suitable for cloud-based 
platforms like AppHarbor. Let me know if you need help 
implementing/architecting a solution that suits your needs!




Best,
Rune
```

Sorry for wasting your time Guys. But thank you for viewing the problem.